# Skype статус

Tags: skype

Я нашел сервис:
http://www.skypeclub.ru/skype_buttons.htm
Но как сделать свою картинку?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script>
</a>  <a href="http://www.skypeclub.ru/" target=_blank>Skype</a>: 
<a href="skype:?chat"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/mediumicon/" style="border: none;" width="26" height="26" alt="My status" />
```

вот их код там строка - `img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/mediumicon/` в src свою картинку пишите и всё

Comment: Если было бы все так просто, я бы сам смог. Там картинка будет мониторится всегда тогда.